# applying appscript code for multiple selections in a drop down to multiple sheets in work book

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Non-coder here. I have found/copied appscript code to enable multiple selections from a drop down list in a Sheet. I've adjusted the code for the Sheet I am referring to and the relevant Columns and it works fine in that Sheet.
How or where do I apply the same basic code to other Sheets in the book while assigning it to different columns on each sheet (e.g. Sheet 1 needs this in Column 6, 5; but Sheet 2 needs this in Column 4, 5)?

This is the code I'm using

```
function onEdit(e) {
var oldValue;
var newValue;
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
if(activeCell.getColumn() == 6 || 7 && 
ss.getActiveSheet().getName()=="Sheet1")
newValue=e.value;
oldValue=e.oldValue;
if(!e.value) {
activeCell.setValue("");
}
else {
if (!e.oldValue) {
activeCell.setValue(newValue);
}
else {
if(oldValue.indexOf(newValue) <0) {
activeCell.setValue(oldValue+', '+newValue);
}
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Start by learning the basics about JavaScript, more specifically about `if` statements (there are other but to keep it simple focus on `if`) and comparison operators.  Then read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers. If you don't understand things in the code from `SpreadsheetApp` methods like `getColumn` read abut them in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/.

Comment: Once you get the very basics, come back and search for questions about using `onEdit` simple trigger. Tip [webapps.se] has a lot of questions like this one. If you still need needs help, please [edit] the question to show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('entry');
  const obj = {'Sheet1':{low:4,high:7},'Sheet2':{low:3,high:6}};
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  //sh.getRange('A1').setValue(JSON.stringify(e));
  const name = sh.getName();
  if( e.range.columnStart > obj[name].low && e.range.columnStart < obj[name].high ) {
    //e.source.toast('flag0');
    if(!e.value) {
      //e.source.toast('flag1');
      e.range.setValue('');
    } else if(!e.oldValue) {
      //e.source.toast('flag2');
      e.range.setValue(e.value);
    } else if(!~e.oldValue.indexOf(e.value)){
      //e.source.toast('flag3');
      e.range.setValue(`${e.oldValue},${e.value}`);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the response but unfortunately I don't know what to do with this.

Comment: Use just like you used the other one.  It requires an onEdit trigger. It meets these requirements: (e.g. Sheet 1 needs this in Column 6, 5; but Sheet 2 needs this in Column 4, 5)?